# Permissions to Allow Another User to Create Alert Emails for pipelines in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-alerts

I am trying to give a user permission to be able to create alerts whenever a pipeline fails in Azure Data Factory. As the owner, I can create the alert without issue, however when another user tries to create this alert, they receive the error message in the screenshot below, and I can't seem to find any logs to give me more information on why this failed.

[When trying to create alert rule, this error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkhsi.png)

I have worked with the user, comparing the permissions I have as the owner, with what permissions I think would give him access, but with over 16000 possible permissions, this is not really feasible to continue. I can't seem to find any relevant information online regarding what permissions he would need. Currently, I have given him the "Data Factory Contributor", and "reader" rule. I also created two custom roles. One for an unrelated issue, giving read and write access to Microsoft.Resources/deployments in the resource group of the DF. And a second custom role, giving read/write/delete to Microsoft.Insights/actiongroups (as he was getting an error saying he didn't have that permission when trying to create this alert previously), as well as R/W/D to Microsoft.AlertsManagement (which didn't seem to resolve the issue, and I have since removed it).

Comment: you need two rules here: 1. read permission onn the target resource.(you have done.) 2. write permission on the resource group in which the alert rule be created( you may neeed check this.). more details here, 'permissions to create metrics alert rule.' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-metric-alert-rule)

Answer (score 0):

***Agreed with @wenbo you also need to give more permission on alert rule, aition group and monitoring.***

**You need below (permission to create alert rule in ADF):**

1. **Read Permission** on the target resource of the alert rule.
2. **Write Permission** on the resource group where the alert rule is being created. (By default, when creating the alert rule from the Azure portal, it's placed in the same resource group as the target resource).
3. **Read Permission** on any associated action group (if applicable).

Other permissions try to assign below roles to your user who can view all monitoring data in a subscription.

- monitoring contributor
- monitoring reader

Comment: Does any of this change if he is trying to create this inside DF Studio? if I understand correctly, I believe I already gave him these permissions. The target of this alert is a pipeline within ADF Studio, not a normal Azure resource. I've added some more information in my post about my custom roles incase I'm misunderstanding, but I think your instructions apply if this was being created at the portal.azure.com site. We are trying to create these at the adf.azure.com site.

Comment: No this are basic permissions to create alerts.